# Using locationClient inside fragment, getLocation(View v) using wrong context

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, android-context

I am following this guild http://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html#GetLocation

I am trying to convert the fragmentActivity into a fragment but i am having some problems which seem to be context based.

This is what logcat says when i click getLocation:

```
05-04 12:19:50.949: E/AndroidRuntime(28565): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method getLocation(View) in the activity class com.wordpress.yourhappening.happening.MainActivity for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'get_location_button'
```

This is the getLocation method:

```
public void getLocation(View v) {

    // If Google Play Services is available
    if (servicesConnected()) {

        // Get the current location
        Location currentLocation = mLocationClient.getLastLocation();

        // Display the current location in the UI
        mLatLng.setText(LocationUtils.getLatLng(getActivity(), currentLocation));
    }
}
```

What i would like to know is what `View` is represented in `getLocation(View v)` and how do i properly point it to my fragment because it seems to be looking for the getlocation button inside my main activity.

Comment: you have this in `public void getLocation(View v)` in `Fragment`??

Comment: Yea, its in my fragment not the main activity.

Comment: then check the below answer it should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am guessing you have this

```
public void getLocation(View v) {
```

in `Fragment`

You need to have this

```
public void getLocation(View v)
```

in `Activity`.

> public static final int onClick
>
> Added in API level 4 Name of the method in this View's context to
>   invoke when the view is clicked. This name must correspond to a public
>   method that takes exactly one parameter of type View. For instance, if
>   you specify android:onClick="sayHello", you must declare a public void
>   sayHello(View v) method of your context (typically, your Activity).

Or in Fragments `onCreateView`

Initialize button as below and set click listener and get rid of `android:onClick:getLocation`

```
Button button =(Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.get_location_button);
button.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
     // do something

    }
});
```

If you need `Context` use `getActivity()`.

Comment: Tried the second method with the fragment `onCreateView`. Works PERFECTLY!!